# C programming where i enter name, and by for loop, it will show

Tags: c

I have to do a program in C (console application), which will be work something like that:

Please enter your name: (put your name here)

How many times i have to show? (here i should enter number) then enter, and it will show it

For example:
Please enter your name: Andrew(enter)
How many times? :2 (enter)
Andrew
Andrew

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char n[20];
    printf("wpisz swoje imie:");
    scanf_s("%s", n, 19);
    printf("ile razy wyswietlic:");
    int i;
    int a = 0;
    scanf_s("%i", &i);
    for (a; 1 < i; a++) {
        printf("%s\n", n);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But something with loop doesnt work. Name which i enter shows up infinity times.
Whats wrong with it? A program which i used to programming is Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Take a look at that look, you have three variables in it: The array `n`, the integer `a` (which **isn't used in the condition**) and the variable `i` which is in the condition.

Comment: also, though unrelated: `scanf_s("%s", n, 19);` => `scanf("%19s", n);`, `_getch();` => `getchar();` and get rid of `conio.h` and `stdafx.h` (replace with `stdio.h`). There's really no need at all to make such a trivial program platform-dependent.

Comment: Am I the only one who felt the Title of the question was like a magic formula ? "where i enter name, and by for loop, it will show" haha ?

Answer (score 2):

your loop is wrong

```
for (a; 1 < i; a++) {
```

`1<i` that condition is never met. For your purpose try

```
for (a; a < i; a++) {
```

Comment: in that case `for (a=0; a < i; a++)` is even better, no need to initialize a beforehand. Let's keep a standard pattern for those loops.

Answer (score 1):

Yor program shows up the name infinity times because:

```
for (a; 1 < i; a++) {
    printf("%s\n", n);
```

}

**1 < i will allways be true**

You need to replace "1 < i" by "a < i", because your 
loop is working with variable "a".

Answer (score 0):

Due to `1 < i` being the stopping condition, your loop will either not run at all, or run forever (well, until you get undefined behaviour due to `a` overflowing, then *anything* could happen). This is because the loop body does not change `i`.

Did you mean `a < i`?

And ditch `<conio.h>`. Most of us don't drive cars that old. Use standard C.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `for (a; 1 < i; a++)`
by      `for (a; a < i; a++)`